# Is it possible to get the Current User name with a Word Add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm working on a Microsoft Word add-in that will be adding comments on behalf of the current user to the word document.  I can't seem to find a way to get the name of the current user dynamically, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you rely on Word's own functionality of adding the current user's name to the added comments? I presume the add in runs under the credentials of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview feature that we can't recommend you use in a production add-in until it is out of preview. But it will enable you to get a token from Azure AD that contains the user's name, email, and ID. The documentation starts here: [SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Answer (score 0):

Save the document and get "lastAuthor":

```js
Word.run(async (context) => {
  const documentProperties = context.document.properties;
  documentProperties.load("lastAuthor");
  await context.sync();
  console.info("Author:", documentProperties.lastAuthor);
)}
```